# Firestore REST API: Query parameters type of object

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, guzzle

I am looking for an advice regarding Google Firestore REST API

I am trying to update the document but keep the data that are not updated
(https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/patch)

I have a document in "message" collection, the document contains following fields: "timestamp", "message" and "user".

If I do the PATCH request to update the "message" field, then the "timestamp" and "user" fields are removed.

There is "Query Parameter" "updateMask" to preven this. The parameter is type of object (DocumentMask). The DocumentMask object looks like this in documentation:

```
{
  "fieldPaths": [
    string
  ],
}
```

There is no example how such a HTTP request should look like.

If I build to request to look like this

```
PATCH https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/messages/someid?updateMask={"fieldPaths":["message"]}
```

The request body contains desired Document

This request will fail on 400, that the parameter with name "updateMask" is unabled to bind...

How can I create such a request with PHP (Guzzle HTTP client)?

Comment: If you're using PHP, consider using the PHP client library. The docs now have PHP snippets: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can not use gRPC due to limitation of our hosting :( but thanks

Comment: Did you found the answer!? I stuck here too.

Answer (score 15):

Each patched field needs to be included as an individual parameter in the query string.
You can use this format for your url :

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<YOUR PROJECT>/databases/(default)/documents/messages/someid?updateMask.fieldPaths=message&updateMask.fieldPaths=<another_field_to_update>&updateMask.fieldPaths=<and_so_on>
```

Fields omitted from the field mask are unchanged, regardless if they are included in the request body Document.

You can use the Google REST API explorer to generate pre-defined URL with Query Parameters and Body from us user friendly interface:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/

Comment: I tried this but after giving the id?updateMask.fieldPaths=message&updateMask.fieldPaths=<other_field_to_ignore> the intended  field is also not getting updated can you help me with some sample code ? @Derek

Comment: @Dinesh Thiyagarajan If my fields to patch in my document are 'message' and 'timestamp', I would use this url string:  
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}?updateMask.fieldPaths=message&updateMask.fieldPaths=timestamp  
2 parameters in the query string for 2 fields in the document.

Comment: how about an actual field path? message.something?

Answer (score 4):

Each patched field needs to be included as an individual parameter in the query string:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<YOUR PROJECT>/databases/(default)/documents/messages/someid?updateMask.fieldPaths=message&updateMask.fieldPaths=<another_field_to_update>&updateMask.fieldPaths=<and_so_on>
```

Fields omitted from the field mask are unchanged, regardless if they are included in the request body Document.

Comment: how about fields that are nested?