# Firebase Cloud Firestore - Fail to write via REST API

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is not an authentication error, write is enabled on the database rules.
My cloud Firestore database looks like the picture below.
There is a COLLECTION called colA, inside it there is a DOCUMENT called docA, and inside it there are some fields (strings) stored.

[image]

On Postman, if I do GET `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/eletronica-ab6b1/databases/(default)/documents/colA/docA`, I do receive the following answer, and it is correct:

```
{
  "name": "projects/eletronica-ab6b1/databases/(default)/documents/colA/docA",
  "fields": {
    "fieldB": {
      "stringValue": "ABCD"
    },
    "fieldA": {
      "stringValue": "888"
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2020-01-31T16:48:26.859181Z",
  "updateTime": "2020-02-05T19:21:49.654340Z"
}
```

Now, when I try to write a new field (fieldC) via POST `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/eletronica-ab6b1/databases/(default)/documents/colA/docA`, with JSON content:

```
{
  "name": "projects/eletronica-ab6b1/databases/(default)/documents/colA/docA",
  "fields": {
    "fieldC": {
      "stringValue": "1000"
    }
  }
}
```

After SEND, I receive this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Document parent name \"projects/eletronica-ab6b1/databases/(default)/documents/colA\" lacks \"/\" at index 60.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I really would like to write strings there via REST API.
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating a document is done with a `PATCH` request, according to the [reference documentation).

A `POST` request is used to create a new document in a collection, which probably explains the error you get: you're pointing to a document, but `POST` expects a collection path.

Comment: Yes, it worked with PATCH. But, using PATCH, after SEND, fieldA and fieldB were deleted and only fieldC remained inside the same DOCUMENT. Do you know how to simply add a field and not exclude the current content?

Comment: You'll need to pass an `updateMask` for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792558 for an example